# Azure Subscription Disabled

Tags: azure, subscription, bizspark

We belong to bizspark program and have an Azure subscription that has been disabled.

Unfortunately, we don't know why and how to see what percentage of our resources is spent.

Anyone know also when Bizspark subscriptions are reenabled?

Comment: I suggest that you contact support.

Comment: We had an account that got disabled even though our spending limit wasn't reached, a couple of days later the account was re-enabled and according to Microsoft support it was a problem on their side. Make sure you haven't reached the limit, and contact support. You can check it somewhere in the portal I think, don't remember exactly.

Comment: I just had the same thing. But whats best is that you don't even get an email. A: warning you or B: telling you its been disabled.

Answer (score 6):

Your account has been disabled because you have reached your spending limit.

To get more information:

1. Go to [manage.windowsazure.com](http://manage.windowsazure.com)
2. click on your email address in the top right corner
3. select Account
4. Log in
5. Click on your subscription and you can view a summary of charges

If you want your account to be re-enabled for this period, you will have to adjust your spending limit above $0.  Be careful though, once you do that, I don't think you can go back.

Comment: We were unable to find any 'Active' subscriptions associated with your account.
SIGN UP FOR WINDOWS AZURE
PRODUCTION PORTAL
WINDOWS AZURE HOME PAGE
CONTACT SUPPORT
in  manage.windowsazure.com I get a page saying: You will need to get a subscription before you can start using Windows Azure
If you have subscriptions that are not active, you can still view them in the Production Portal. Any help?

Comment: Let me ask this stupid question real quick to ensure we are on the same page.  Are you logging in with the same account the set up your subscription to begin with?

Answer (score 5):

Try going to https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions (log in if necessary), and once you're there, click on the subscription in question.  That should take you to a summary page on the billing for the account.

By default, it shows only the common usage metrics - it's likely you have exceeded one of these, and it should be easy to figure out which component put you over, but if not, try clicking the drop down that says "Show Common Usage" and change that to "Show All Usage".

As to your second question, the disable/re-enable cycle happens monthly, and if you've had your account for more than a month, it should have "snapped" to a period that spans from the first to the last of the month.  If not, your period could be different, spanning from the first day you had the account to 30 days after, and "snapping" at that point, or it could be a pro-rated period that is from the first day of your account to the last day of the same month, with usage quotas pro-rated into it.

Regardless, your stuff should be re-enabled on the first day of the next billing period (which could be today, or perhaps September 1st, depending on what put you over).

Answer (score 1):

I did face a similar issue with manage.windowsazure.com portal, but I'm successful in creating apps/site with the same subscription on the new portal (portal.azure.com).  Once after creating an App/site in the new portal, this problem is resolved (even I'm able to publish from Visual Studio).

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but had definitely not reached my spending limit, I had $100 credit left. Yet I was getting the following message

> We were unable to find any Active subscriptions associated with your account. SIGN     UP FOR WINDOWS AZURE PRODUCTION PORTAL WINDOWS AZURE HOME PAGE CONTACT SUPPORT

In my case, it was because I had logged in to MSDN at some time with company credentials.  So although the URL for my azure indicated my username and account such as:

https://manage.windowsazure.com/@mynamegmail.onmicrosoft.com#Workspaces/All/dashboard

Even though I had already selected sign out on MSDN, Somehow it was mixing the two accounts.  I had to sign out of Azure from the Manage Azure screen and sign back in again with my personal Microsoft account.

Comment: I have the same issue with confused logins. I use Chrome for one and IE for the other.